# LESS variable value to string

Tags: css, less

I'm updating some old CSS sheets and creating a new LESS sheet for my project. In the old CSS sheet I have, I have two hex values that are used to make a gradient.

The hex values are passed like hex values in one instance like this:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0079bc), to(#00509d));
```

And as string values in another instance in the same rule like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00509d', endColorstr='#00509d');
```

If I'm trying to maintain the two hex values as variables in the new LESS file, how can I pass the hex value variable as a string in the second instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
.gradientMix(@hex1, @hex2) {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@hex1), to(@hex2));
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{hex1}', endColorstr='@{hex2}');
}

.gradientMix(#0079bc,#00509d);
```

Which outputs:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0079bc), to(#00509d));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0079bc', endColorstr='#00509d');
```

Notice how I accessed the variable when it is within the quote marks by surrounding the name with brackets, like so: `@{hex1}` to access the `@hex1` variable inside a string.